# How do I get Jquery to toggle display

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a FAQ page that toggles display for the answers.

Here is the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.faqlink').click(function () {
        $('.hiddenFAQ').hide();
        $(this).next('.hiddenFAQ').show();
    });
});
```

The CSS

```
.hiddenFAQ {
    display:none;
}
```

And the HTML

```
    <a class="faqlink" href="#">Link 1</a>

    <div class="hiddenFAQ"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
```

Right now it will display, but the only way to make it go away is to refresh the page. How can I make it toggle instead? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.faqlink').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.hiddenFAQ').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4Tkh8/1/)**